# How to Display the Indice Page Numbers in Bold?

Tags: formatting, indexing, makeindex

As the title suggests, given an index, say

[image]

produced by the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\begin{document}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-1}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-2}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-3}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I would like to able to display the page numbers in bold? Can this be done collectively? Can this be done selectively? If so, can someone indicate how to do this? I found no posts which anser this question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`makeindex`](//ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/makeindex) (section **2.2 The Basics**, p 5):

> In some indexes, certain page numbers are specially formatted - for example, an italic page number may indicate the primary reference, and an `n` after a page number may denote that the item appears in a footnote on that page. MakeIndex makes it easy to format an individual page number any way you want. For any string of characters `σ`, the command
> `\index{...|σ}` produces a page number of the form `\σ{n}`. Similarly, the command `\index{...|(σ}` may produce a page number of the form `\σ{n–m}`.

So, to make an individual entry's page number appear **bold**, use `\index{Heading@!Entry-1|textbf}`. To make all page numbers appear **bold**, you could do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}

\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-1}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-2}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!Entry-3}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the documentation and the very helpful answer.