# Making Index Page Citations Bold without Obliterating "See{Another Indice}"

Tags: indexing, algorithms, bold, makeindex, renewcommand

Previously, I had posted the question  [How to Display the Indice Page Numbers in Bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580944/how-to-display-the-indice-page-numbers-in-bold)

and received a very fine answer, which has served me well.

However, I have since discovered a conflict making page numbers bold when using the aglorithm

```
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%
```

in conjunction with index entries that refer the reader to another entry (e.g., `\index{Heading2|see{Heading}}`).

Consider the code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
%delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill "
%delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}{%
  \nobreak\dotfill\ \nobreak
}
\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
  \par
  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%
  }
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
\vspace{27pt}
\hfil   \tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!35,
    line width=1.3pt,
    inner sep=10pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
    minimum width=1.25in
  ] {#1};%
  \nopagebreak
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}%
\hfil }


% Make all page numbers in index bold
%\let\oldindex\index
%\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
%  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
%}%


\begin{document}
\LARGE

\newpage A sentence\index{Heading@!IndiceA}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!IndiceB}
\newpage Another sentence\index{Heading@!IndiceC}
\index{Heading2|see{Heading}}
\index{A@\textbf{A}|see{\textbf{B}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index

[image]

However, when I run the code with the algorithm

```
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%
```

the ``*see*'' indices disappear:

[image]

QUESTION: Can anyone explain why this happens; and how I may correct it so that I may have citations pages in bold simultaneously with *see* indices that direct the reader to other entries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the problem if you look at the `.idx` file that your document generates: you will find that your see entries create something that looks like this:

```
\indexentry{A|see{B}|textbf}{1}
             ⬆︎     ⬆︎
```

Notice that there are *two* instances of `|` in the `\indexentry`. Then, when you run makeindex, pay attention to the output:

```
Scanning input file xx.idx....done (1 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
                                                        ----------
```

That bit about index entries being rejected is your clue. If you then look in the `.ilg` file, you will see:

```
!! Input index error (file = xx.idx, line = 2):
   -- Extra `|' at position 9 of first argument.
```

which tells you exactly what's gone wrong. When makeindex saw the two `|`s in the input, it rejected the index entry.

So the gotcha here is that you can't just blindly apply `|textbf` to every index entry. If, in fact, you do want to have every page number in the index in boldface (and do you really?), the way to manage this is through the index style. Adding this to your `.ist` file (or creating one with it) will cause all page numbers to be emboldened:

```
delim_0 ", \\textbf{"
delim_1 ", \\textbf{"
delim_2 ", \\textbf{"
delim_n "}, \\textbf{"
delim_t "}"
encap_prefix "}\\"
encap_infix "{\\textbf{"
encap_suffix "}"
```

You would then use this by running makeindex specifying the style with the `-s` option to indicate the style, e.g.,

```
makeindex  -s test.ist xx
```

Now I see that you're using the `imakeidx` package which will run `makeindex` for you automatically.¹ In that instance, you will need to modify your `\makeindex` command to specify that it requires a special index style² by changing it to

```
\makeindex[options=-s mystyle]
```

of course changing `mystyle` to whatever you've named your index style.

---

1. I'm not convinced this is a good idea, although I will note that TeXshop provides minimal integration with makeindex and requires users to drop down to a command line to run the command if they need to specify an index style so I can see the motivation.
2. On the flip side, this is a nice feature. There is otherwise no other way to specify an index style to `makeindex` other than through remembering to indicate it when running `makeindex` at the command line which is probably why index styles are so rarely used.

Comment: Do you have a working example to post that solves the problem? If so, please post it. Thank you.

Comment: @michristians Working example to solve the problem: Don't redefine `\index`, change your `\makeindex` line as described above. Put the stuff beginning with `delim_0` into `mystyle.ist` and it will work.